# control the pageblocktable visibility

Tags: pageblocktable

I have 3 dependent dropdowns in my VF page. Upon selection of these, a pageblocktable is displayed. I want the table to be displayed only after the selection of 3 dropdowns. I dont want the table to be visible on PageLoad. How do i control the visibility of this table?

Comment: yes rendered conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Add a property to your controller that checks the values selected in the 3 dropdowns:

```
public Boolean renderTable {
    get {
        return !String.isEmpty(dropDown1)
                && !String.isEmpty(dropDown2)
                && !String.isEmpty(dropDown3);
    }
}
```

and render your table accordingly:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable rendered="{!renderTable}" ...
```

You will need to add an `onchange` [apex:actionSupport](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm) to the dropdowns that re-renders the containing element of the apex:pageBlockTable when any of them change.